# Xcode: Continuous Integration and Github

Tags: ios, xcode, git

Is there anyway to configure OSX Server, Github and Xcode's bots to withhold pushing changes to a Github repo until when/if the bot integrates successfully and passes all of its test? Right now, my server is just looking at the Github repo and attempting to integrate whenever a change is pushed.